# What is the name of the animal vaccine created in space? (according to Robert Zubrin)

Tags: microgravity, astrobiology, research

I'm reading "The Case for Space" and on pg 47 of the book, Zubrin mentions that some sort of animal vaccine was created thanks to research done in microgravity and in space. He goes on to say that this has generated BILLIONS in revenue/value to the companies involved.

He doesn't cite who it is, what the vaccine is, etc... Further searches have yielded nothing for me. The closest I can find is Astrogenetix' Salmonella Vaccine, but this did not pass human trials and was never commercialized.

This is really bugging me + making me doubt all the ideas/data in the book...

Any help would be EXTREMELY appreciated.

-- Edit --

Since people asked, here is the quote in question:

> Orbital research labs that take advantage of the unique zero-gravity
>   and high-vacuum environments available in low Earth orbit could also
>   be producing a profit in the relatively near future. The product of
>   such labs is knowledge, which is massless. Thus, precious little raw
>   material is required, at least in principle, to produce marketable
>   products of enormous cash value. This is so forcefully the case that
>   even the vastly overpriced space shuttle managed to produce what might
>   be considered a kind of profit during **two ten-day missions in which
>   zero-gravity experiments helped researchers determine the structure of
>   certain animal viruses, thereby enabling the development of veterinary
>   vaccines worth several billions to the economy.**

Comment: Could you quote the relevant part of the book, just a paragraph or two? Many of us don't have the book available, and any clue could help.

Comment: Silly me, thank you for asking! I just edited the question to include the quote. That's literally all he says.

Comment: Thanks! It is some help because now we know it was shuttle.

Comment: You could try emailing him and asking

Comment: I was unable to find anything.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Good idea on reaching out to Robert Zubrin. I'll do that.